# How to read geojson file using TopoJSON

Tags: json, d3.js, topojson

I am working to resize the json file that I have automatically after reading json file. But I am getting errors.

```
$.getJSON("data/cities.json", function (data) {
        getData = topojson.feature(data, data.features);
        console.log( getData)
    });
```

Cities.json look like

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "features": [{
     "geometry": {
         "type": "MultiPolygon",
         "coordinates": [
             [
                 [
                     [-73.8283219965448, 40.8446061654002],
                     [-73.828397789942, 40.844583182304],
                     [-73.8285477331865, 40.8448132168025],
                     [-73.8284744943625, 40.8448401137412],
                     [-73.8283219965448, 40.8446061654002]
                 ]
             ]
         ]
     },
     "type": "Feature",
 , {
     "geometry": {
         "type": "MultiPolygon",
         "coordinates": [
             [
                 [
                     [-73.832361912256, 40.8488019205992],
                     [-73.832369554769, 40.8487286684528],
                     [-73.8327312374341, 40.8487518102579],
                     [-73.8327304815978, 40.8487590590352],
                     [-73.8327235953166, 40.8488250624279],
                     [-73.832361912256, 40.8488019205992]
                 ]
             ]
         ]
     },
     "type": "Feature"
 } 


}
```

How can I load json data using getJSON then pass it to topojson

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'feature' (index):45

Comment: how are you including topojson in your page? seems like it is not loading properly

Comment: <script src="http://prag.ma/code/d3-cartogram/lib/topojson.js"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoJSON and TopoJSON are two different formats. You cannot use TopoJSON functions to process GeoJSON. You need to convert the GeoJSON you have to TopoJSON (see [the commandline reference](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference)) and then load that.

Comment: Can I convert GeoJSON to TopoJSON automatically inside code, I am updating the geojson every 12 hours. That's why I need to automate this process. The reason I want to convert to TopJSON is to reduce the size of this file (>300 mb)

Comment: There's no point in converting to TopoJSON in Javascript once you have transferred the data already.